# Create and import a custom python package - import doesn't work in the root

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, sys

I'm totally new to Python, and I want to create my first Python library for peronal uses.

I'm using Python 2.7.5, and running the IDLE interface.

So far, what I understood from the documentation and related questions is that:

- Python goes through a list of directories listed in sys.path to find scripts and libraries
- The package directory must contain a `__init__.py` file, which can be empty
- The module I want to create should be a `modulename.py` file with the code inside the package directory

(Sources: http://www.johnny-lin.com/cdat_tips/tips_pylang/path.html --- https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html)

And here is what I tried that fails:

- Created a personal package directory `C:\....\pythonlibs`
- Created a subpackage dir `C:\....\pythonlibs\package`
- Created the `__init__.py` file inside both folders
- Created the `mymodule.py` file in the `packacge` dir

And then in the IDLE used this code:

```
import sys     
sys.path.append(r'C:\....\pythonlibs')
```

First issue:

> Currently I have to do this append **every time** I enter the IDLE. How can I keep the directory in sys.path permanently just as there are a lot of other directories there?

Then I tried importing my package:

```
import pythonlibs #fails!! why?      
import pythonlibs.package #fails!! why?       
import package #works
```

The error is: `ImportError: No module named pythonlibs`

Second issue?

> This seems to be against the documentation, why can't I import from the root `pythonlibs` folder?

Comment: Because your imports are relative to the path you added: `r'C:\....\pythonlibs'`. If there was a `C:\....\pythonlibs\pythonlibs` directory then you could `import pythonlibs`. You might want to change your path addition to `r'C:\....\'` and look up the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

With line

```
sys.path.append(r'C:\....\pythonlibs')
```

you are instructing interpreter to start looking for modules (libraries) in this directory. Since this directory does not contain `pythonlibs` folder (the parent does), it can't import it.

Similarly - because it contains the module `package`, it can import it.